# Шаблон списка c++

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

есть двусвязный список, необходимо сделать для него шаблон, чтобы можно было взаимодействовать с разными типами данных, подскажите как правильно это сделать???

```
template <class V>
struct Node
{
    V data;
    Node* next;
    Node* prev;
};

template <class V>
Node* first(V d) 
{
    Node* pv = new Node;
    pv->data = d;
    pv->next = NULL;
    pv->prev = NULL;
    return pv;
};
```

ПОдчёркивает Node* с ошибкой: отсутствует список аргументов для "Node".

Comment: Попробуйте написать `Node<V>` вместо `Node`

Comment: Да,спасибо все заработало,кроме удаления списка

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не забывайте, что просто `Node` нет, есть `Node<V>`

```
template <class V>
Node<V>* first(V d)
{
    Node<V>* pv = new Node<V>;
    pv->data = d;
    pv->next = NULL;
    pv->prev = NULL;
    return pv;
};
```